# Use View as Button - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there anyway to use the view as button? Im kinda clueless of what Im doing.

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.vicon} onClick={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MessageScreen')}>
      <Image source={require('../misc/icon1.png')} style={styles.iicon} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.vtexts} onClick={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MessageScreen')}>
      <Text style={styles.tname}>{this.state.name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.tmessage}>{this.state.message}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

this is me so far. I need to use the view as a button to redirect to the messageScreen. Hope someone can help me. Thanksss

Comment: you can use TouchableHighlight

Comment: Im sorry but can you be more specific? How should I change the View to TouchableHighlight or should I wrap it,and so on.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html & https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.html

Comment: if you need touch actions. use touchable components instead view

Comment: use touchableOpacity. you need to wrap view with touchableOpacity and declare click event there.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put TouchableWithoutFeedback inside the View and then put the navigate function in onPress prop.

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.vicon}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MessageScreen')}>
            <Image source={require('../misc/icon1.png')} style={styles.iicon} />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.vtexts}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MessageScreen')}>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.tname}>{this.state.name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.tmessage}>{this.state.message}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

You can play around with the style prop to get the desired styling.

Happy Coding!

Comment: As I know `TouchableNativeFeedback` is only for Android .

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @oma, i have edited the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TouchableOpacity`. Is exactly what you need, check here the definition from react-native documentation:

> A wrapper for making views respond properly to touches. On press down,
>   the opacity of the wrapped view is decreased, dimming it.

You can find details here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html